# Domain Access: Subdomain -> same views-path - different view?

Tags: 7, views, domain-access

I am a beginner by module domain-access and have a question.

standarddomain: `example.com`
subdomain: `m.example.com`

In my standarddomain i use a views-page with path `example.com/myviewsgallery` (Views A) - this viewspage show 50 results, has a special pager and so on.

On my subdomain I need the same path `m.example.com/myviewsgallery` but here I will use an other (minimized) Views (Views B) with reduced results and other pager (and so on). The mobile version is intended to display reduced content.

I would like to use a mobile-switcher that automatically redirects the mobile user to the mobile subdomain - to the same path as on the desktop version.

But the problem is, I cant use a other (reduced) View-Page on my mobile-subdomain which has the same Views-path like standardomain.

At the moment:

- `example.com/myviewsgallery` (show Views A)
- `m.example.com/myviewsgallery` (show Views A too, but i need Views B
  under this path)

Is there anyone here who can tell me how to solve this problem?

Excuse me my bad English, I hope nevertheless that I could bring the problem understandably.

Many thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: You can rendered both view pages on same link one after the other and theme these two views with different ids using views theme suggestion and by css and @media query, just hide that hide which you don't want on desktop version and vice versa. Hope you get this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based off [@Sugandh Khanna](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/24334/sugandh-khanna) answer, follow these steps:

1. Make View 2 as an attachment and attached to View 1.
2. In mobile view, add the css `.view-content {  display: none  }`
3. In desktop view, add the css `.attachment {  display: none  }`